# one to many relationship not working in Laravel

Tags: laravel

I am doing a project with Laravel. I would like to return the language of a customer... but for some reason I return an empty response. One customer can have only one language and one language can be spoken by many customers.

This is the model of Language:

```
public function customers()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Customer', 'language_id', 'id');
    }
```

This is the model of Customer:

```
public function language()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Language', 'id', 'language_id');
}
```

And this is what I tried to return:

```
return Customer::where('customer_id', $customerId)->first()->language()->pluck('language_id');
```

I should receive values like `FR`, `IT`, `EN`... but I receive only `[]`.

Can help?

Comment: You don't need `id` and `language_id`; those are automatically determined by your Model names and primary key :) You can just use `hasMany(Customer::class)` and `belongsTo(Language::class)`, and that might actually solve it :)

Comment: If you change relationship at the customer model like this ```public function language() { return $this->belongsTo('App\Language', 'language_id')->withDefault(); }```, what do you get ?

Comment: I receive the correct return!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the wrong in your relation in:

```
Customer Model:

public function language()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Language',  'language_id','id');
}
```

like in [doc](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many) the second parameter in the belongsTo should be the foreign_key column.
and you can omit them if you followed Laravel convention for naming columns